# incorrect R-squared calculated using linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am doing a really simple linear regression in R but the calculated R^2 just doesn't seem right. The regression I have done is the following:

```
data(cats)
fit = lm(Hwts ~ Bwts+0, data = cats)
summary(fit)
```

The results I got from this regression is the following:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cats$Hwt ~ cats$Bwt + 0)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4563 -0.9980 -0.1003  1.0044  5.2623 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
cats$Bwt  3.90711    0.04364   89.53   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.449 on 143 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9825,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9823 
F-statistic:  8015 on 1 and 143 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

calculated R-sqaured is as high as 0.9825, but a simple plot on the data would give you an intuition that R-squared can not be that high. If I calculate R-squared using the equation given by Wikipedia, I got the following results:

```
1-sum(residuals(fit1)^2)/sum((cats$Hwt - mean(cats$Hwt))^2)
[1] 0.6459604
```

This R-squared of 0.6459 definition look more reasonable, and I found that if I allow intercept in the regression I would get an R-squared around this number:

```
fit = lm(Hwt ~ Bwt, data = cats)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Hwt ~ Bwt, data = cats)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5694 -0.9634 -0.0921  1.0426  5.1238 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.3567     0.6923  -0.515    0.607    
Bwt           4.0341     0.2503  16.119   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.452 on 142 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6466,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6441 
F-statistic: 259.8 on 1 and 142 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

How come the R-squared become so different when I allow or disallow intercept? Please comment.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the R^2 calculation uses a baseline prediction of 0 for all observations when you fit a model with no intercept term. As a result, the relevant R^2 calculation is:

```
library(boot)
fit <- lm(Hwt ~ Bwt+0, data = cats)
summary(fit)$r.squared
# [1] 0.9824721
1-sum(residuals(fit)^2)/sum(cats$Hwt^2)
# [1] 0.9824721
```

Basically the R^2 returned by `lm` is compared to a baseline model that does not have access to any of the variables (Bwt in this case). If you're fitting models with no intercept, the baseline model must predict 0 for all observations since it can't fit an intercept term to the training set mean outcome value.